# is "purile" a word?

Tags: meaning

I can't find it on any dictionary. It could be spelt wrong but google doesn't correct it. it could be obsolete but any such (outdated) record doesn't seem to be in existence. the word could either be extinct or unreal. but I could have sworn I've read it somewhere

Comment: [Puerile](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/puerile?q=puerile) is the correct spelling.

Comment: It simply means **childish**.  (As any say French speaker would know.)  This is a word that is often **used badly**.  People sometimes say "puerile argument" just meaning "very very hopeless and stupid argument". But a "puerile argument" is a childish argument. That's specific.

Answer (score 4):

It is a word, but it's spelled "**puerile**".

**pu·er·ile** adjective \ˈpyu̇(-ə)r-əl, -ˌī(-ə)l\
: silly or childish especially in a way that shows a lack of seriousness or good judgment

[Meaning](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/puerile)